# Is there any quadratic programming function that can have both lower and upper bounds - Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, quadratic-programming, scipy-optimize

Normally I have been using [GNU Octave](https://octave.sourceforge.io/optim/function/quadprog.html) to solve quadratic programming problems.

I solve problems like

```
x = 1/2x'Qx + c'x
```

With subject to

```
A*x <= b
lb <= x <= ub
```

Where `lb` and `ub` are lower bounds and upper bounds, e.g limits for `x`

My Octave code looks like this when I solve. Just one simple line

```
U = quadprog(Q, c, A, b, [], [], lb, ub);
```

The square brackets `[]` are empty because I don't need the equality constraints

```
Aeq*x = beq,
```

So my question is:
Is there a easy to use quadratic solver in Python for solving problems

```
x = 1/2x'Qx + c'x
```

With subject to

```
A*x <= b
lb <= x <= ub
```

Or subject to

```
b_lb <= A*x <= b_ub
lb <= x <= ub
```

Comment: look in `scipy`.

Comment: Another option is to use [cvxopt](https://cvxopt.org)

Comment: You could also take a look at [qpsolvers](https://github.com/stephane-caron/qpsolvers)

Comment: have a look at [lsq_linear](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a general quadratic programming solver like `quadprog`, I would suggest the open-source software [cvxopt](https://cvxopt.org/) as noted in one of the comments. This is robust and really state-of-the-art. The main contributor is a major expert in the field and the co-author of a [classic book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IUZdAAAAQBAJ) on Convex Optimization.

The function you want to use is [cvxopt.solvers.qp](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#cvxopt.solvers.qp). A simple wrapper to use it in `Numpy` like `quadprog` is the following. Note that bounds can be included as a special case of inequality constraints.

```
import numpy as np
from cvxopt import matrix, solvers

def quadprog(P, q, G=None, h=None, A=None, b=None, options=None):
     """
    Quadratic programming problem with both linear equalities and inequalities

        Minimize      0.5 * x @ P @ x + q @ x
        Subject to    G @ x <= h
        and           A @ x = b
    """
    P, q = matrix(P), matrix(q)

    if G is not None:
        G, h = matrix(G), matrix(h)

    if A is not None:
        A, b = matrix(A), matrix(b)

    sol = solvers.qp(A, b, G, h, A, b, options=options)

    return np.array(sol['x']).ravel()
```

`cvxopt` used to be difficult to install, but is nowadays also included in the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/) and can be installed (even on Windows) with `conda install cvxopt`.

If instead, you are interested in the more specific case of linear least-squares optimisation with bounds, which is a subset of the general quadratic programming, namely

```
Minimize || A @ x - b ||
subject to lb <= x <= ub
```

Then `Scipy` has the specific function `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear(A, b, bounds)`.

Note that the accepted answer is a very inefficient approach and should not be recommended. It makes no use of the crucial fact that the function you want to optimize is quadratic but instead uses a generic nonlinear optimization program and does not even specify the analytic gradient.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own solver based `scipy.optimize`, here is a small example on how  to code your custom python `quadprog()`:

```py
# python3
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

class quadprog(object):

    def __init__(self, H, f, A, b, x0, lb, ub):
        self.H    = H
        self.f    = f
        self.A    = A
        self.b    = b
        self.x0   = x0
        self.bnds = tuple([(lb, ub) for x in x0])
        # call solver
        self.result = self.solver()

    def objective_function(self, x):
        return 0.5*np.dot(np.dot(x.T, self.H), x) + np.dot(self.f.T, x)

    def solver(self):
        cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: self.b - np.dot(self.A, x)})
        optimum = optimize.minimize(self.objective_function, 
                                    x0          = self.x0.T,
                                    bounds      = self.bnds,
                                    constraints = cons, 
                                    tol         = 10**-3)
        return optimum
```

Here is how to use this, using the same variables from the first example provided in [matlab-quadprog](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html):

```py
# init vars
H  = np.array([[ 1, -1],
               [-1,  2]])

f  = np.array([-2, -6]).T

A  = np.array([[ 1, 1],
               [-1, 2],
               [ 2, 1]])

b  = np.array([2, 2, 3]).T
x0 = np.array([1, 2])
lb = 0
ub = 2

# call custom quadprog
quadprog  = quadprog(H, f, A, b, x0, lb, ub)
print(quadprog.result)
```

The output of this short snippet is:

```py
     fun: -8.222222222222083
     jac: array([-2.66666675, -4.        ])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 8
     nit: 2
    njev: 2
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.66666667, 1.33333333])
```

For more information on how to use `scipy.optimize.minimize` please refer to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`solve_qp`](https://scaron.info/doc/qpsolvers/quadratic-programming.html#qpsolvers.solve_qp) function from [qpsolvers](https://github.com/stephane-caron/qpsolvers). It solves quadratic programs in the following form:

```
minimize_x  1/2 x' P x + q'x
subject to  G x <= h
            A x == b
            lb <= x <= ub
```

The function wraps the many QP solvers available in Python ([full list here](https://github.com/stephane-caron/qpsolvers#solvers)) via its `solver` keyword argument. Make sure to try different solvers to find the one that fits your problem best.

Here is a snippet for solving a small problem:

```py
from numpy import array, dot
from qpsolvers import solve_qp

M = array([[1., 2., 0.], [-8., 3., 2.], [0., 1., 1.]])
P = dot(M.T, M)  # this is a positive definite matrix
q = dot(array([3., 2., 3.]), M)
G = array([[1., 2., 1.], [2., 0., 1.], [-1., 2., -1.]])
h = array([3., 2., -2.])
A = array([1., 1., 1.])
b = array([1.])

x = solve_qp(P, q, G, h, A, b, solver="osqp")
print(f"QP solution: x = {x}")
```

And if you are interested linear least-squares with linear or box (bounds) constraints, there is also a [`solve_ls`](https://scaron.info/doc/qpsolvers/least-squares.html#qpsolvers.solve_ls) function. Here is a [short tutorial](https://scaron.info/blog/linear-least-squares-in-python.html) on solving such problems.

Comment: There is an easier way to do this. Use Hilderth's algorithm. Few lines of MATLAB-code that solve QP :)